# Continuïty of function between two metric spaces

Tags: derivatives, continuity, metric-spaces

the last few days I have been busy studying Analysis and more specific the topic of metric spaces. I was making some exercices on the continuïty of functions between metric spaces and stumbled upon the following problem: Let $C^1([-1;1])$ be the vector space of function going from $[-1;1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which are one time differentiable and for which its derivative is also continuous. On $C^1([-1;1])$ we define the $d_{\infty}$-metric which is defined as $d_{\infty}(f,g) = sup (|f(x) - g(x)|| x \in [-1;1])$. On $\mathbb{R}$ we just take the normal euclidean metric. The question or task is to determine wether the following function is continuous or not
$$D:C^1([-1;1]) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: f \rightarrow f'(0)$$
I'm very confused in the way how to approach this problem that is with the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition or with the convergence property of continuïty. If anyone has a tip how to start solving this problem, any help would as always be greatly appreciated :))

P.S: I tried to approach this problem by thinking that if $d_{\infty}(f,g)$ becomes small so should f'(0) and g'(0) be close together but I don't know how to correctly proof this.

Comment: Use mean value theorem

Comment: Thx for the tip, but I can't seem to figure out where to use the theorem :((

Comment: My guess is that it's not continuous because derivatives and the sup norm don't really work well with each other. An increasingly zig-zag-like function (that is smoothed out so it's still $C^1$) would have arbitrarily large derivative at $0$.

Comment: And what if we check the continuïty in a "good behaving" function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequence $f_n = \frac{1}{n}arctan(xn^2)$. The derivative of $f_n$ is $\frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{1 + x^2 n^4} n^2$, which, when evaluated at $0$ is $n$.

However, $f_n$ converges pointwise to the zero function. As $[-1, 1]$ is compact, the convergence is uniform so $f_n$ converges to $0$ uniformly. However, $f_n'(0)$ diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: thank you for the counterexample. However I still find the question strange since it suggests that I go through all possible function but that is pretty impossible